# Are timestamps created with new GPT partition tables?

Tags: gpt, partition-table

Are timestamps created with new GPT partition tables?

If so, where are they (i.e, headers, entries, GUIDs, labels)? How are they accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren’t necessarily any timestamps created with new GPT partition tables. [The GPT layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) doesn’t include any timestamp fields. If a partition is given a version 1 GUID (see [RFC-4122 sections 4.1.3 and 4.1.4](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122)), the generated GUID will include a timestamp; but any other version won’t. Most partition GUIDs I’ve seen use version 4 and therefore don’t contain a timestamp.